# PHP Multidimensional array with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

Trying to build the multidimensional array with a foreach using record from a db...

[image]

```
$servDetails = array(
    // CSS Servers
    'css' => array(
        'server1' => array(
            'id' => 'id1',
            'type' => 'css',
            'host' => 'ip:port'
        ),
        'server2' => array(
            'id' => 'id2',
            'type' => 'css',
            'host' => 'ip:port'
        )
    )
);
```

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Use a loop. This is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have executed and have populated an associative array:

```
// create your containing array
$servDetails = array('css' => array());

// iterate over the results
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $servDetails['css'][$result['server_name']] = array(
        'id' => $result['server_id'],
        'type' => 'css',
        'host' => $result['server_ip'] . ':' . $result['server_port']
    );
}
```

I'm not sure where the `'css'` portion comes from in your sample, so you may have to adjust this to make it dynamic (if it is in fact dynamic).

You could also build this array structure directly when pulling the results from the db:

```
if ($results = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($result = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        $servDetails['css'][$result['server_name']] = array(
            'id' => $result['server_id'],
            'type' => 'css',
            'host' => $result['server_ip'] . ':' . $result['server_port']
        );
    }
```